# Is this phrase correct?

Tags: phrases

If I say "youngest elder brother", I wish to refer to that elder brother of mine who is younger than all other siblings but elder than me. Is it the correct way to express?

Comment: The clearest way to say this is probably "the youngest of my older brothers". However you would still get people looking at you with blank expressions as it's not a common expression.

Answer (score -4):

"youngest elder brother" is not correct usage as youngest means the smallest of all and as you are smallest it should be simply "elder brother".